# How to redirect all sub urls just to the main page

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Super new to varnish. As the title states. I want to redirect anything under example.com/* to just https://example.com/

so far I've tried

```
if (client.ip != "127.0.0.1" && req.http.host == "example.com") {
        set req.http.x-redir = "https://example.com";
        error 850 "Moved Permanently";
      }
```

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this specific section of a tutorial I wrote: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/redirect/#http-to-https-redirections.

Here's the code I would use for that:

```
vcl 4.1;

import proxy;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = 8080;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if ((req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto && req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto != "https") || 
        (req.http.Scheme && req.http.Scheme != "https")) {
        return (synth(750));
    } elseif (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto && !req.http.Scheme && !proxy.is_ssl()) {
        return (synth(750));
    }
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 750) {
        set resp.status = 301;
        set resp.http.location = "https://" + req.http.Host + req.url;
        set resp.reason = "Moved";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

This tutorial checks 3 things:

- Whether or not the URL scheme of the request is sent via the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header
- Whether or not the URL scheme of the request is sent via the `X-Scheme` header which is part of HTTP/2
- Whether or not the PROXY protocol was used and the PROXY TLV attributes contains the scheme

When either of these checks concludes that plain HTTP is used, the `return(synth(750))` return statement is used to return a synthetic response.

In the `vcl_synth` subroutine, status code `750` is caught and results in a 301 redirect to the HTTPS version of that request.

> The `X-Forwarded-Proto` header should be set by your TLS PROXY if you're connecting to Varnish using regular HTTP.
>
> If instead you're using the PROXY protocol to connect to Varnish, you should have a look at the following tutorial: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/proxy-protocol-varnish/